# How to get the string representation of property names from a given typescript type

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript so this question might be trivial.

Say I defined a type like

```js
type MyType = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}
```

and an object like

```js
const o:MyType = {
  name:"John Doe",
  age:42
}
```

I could access the the name via `o["name"]`.

Is it possible instead of using "name" something more safe like `o[MyTypeProp.name]` where `MyTypeProp.name` is derived from the actual type and contains every propertyname?

I was looking into [MappedTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and something similar to

```js
type MyTypeProp = {
  [Property in keyof MyType]: Property;
};
```

which gave me not what I was hoping for.

My usecase is to make testing easier: I have a bunch of properties to test whether they are disabled writing this

```
expect(allDisabled(model, ["isTrackingPresent", "isDistributionPresent", ...]))
```

is more comfortable than testing each and every manually.

On top getting rid of those "magic strings" would be more comfortable.

Comment: so you want to access the actual property, right? If yes, then no, it's not possible since types will be gone in runtime.

Comment: @wonderflame I expected that there is a languge feature which automagically generates something like `const MyTypeProp ={name:"name", age="age"}` which would do the trick.

Comment: This feature is called Javascript :D. Unfortunately, it's not possible with types

Comment: Okay this "superset" has no super powers, I see XD

Comment: do you want to adjust your requirements or should I just write an answer saying that this is not possible?

Comment: @wonderflame if that is the answer ("no") then write it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be possible to generate some runtime constants using types, since all types will be gone in runtime. If the variables are correctly typed then there is no need for this kind of object.

It would be possible to generate a type out of the object that would show the structure of the type:

```
const factory = {
  name: {
   type: "string",
  },
  data: {
   type: "object", 
   fields: {
     age: {
       type: "number"
     }

   }
  }
  
} as const
```

Then have a type for converting "string", "number" to actual type:

```
type TypeMap = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
}
```

And using some *mapped type* you could recursively go through the `factory` and generate a type.